# How do I get a list of old->new rewritten commit SHAs from 'git filter-branch'?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

After running `git filter-branch`, how do I get a list of old commit SHAs as rewritten by filter-branch to their new corresponding commit SHAs?

For example, something similar to:

```
b19fd985746c1f060f761d42d353e387bec243fb -> c8ab40ef9bae3b58642a8d1e5b90720d093a60b5
c5ebba1eeb92ca76c0effa32de14178ec7f07db6 -> 4d5a9958b98dbcfa47ce1354bb2af4cc77904639
705f71543235b872ca3e1067538e36d14044429d -> d2aafbd6e5b91955b62dee34f4a0abf0171ba016
```

Where the left column is the list of original SHAs, and the right column are the new SHAs after being rewritten by filter-branch.

I see that the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_filters) for filter-branch mentions a `map` function, but I don't understand whether that's useful here, or if it is, how to use it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had to go poking around the source for `git-filter-branch` to work this one out. It's not documented (as far as I can tell), but the old commit ID is explicitly exported as `$GIT_COMMIT`. This worked for me:

```
$ git filter-branch --your-filters-here --commit-filter 'echo -n "${GIT_COMMIT}," >>/tmp/log; git commit-tree "$@" | tee -a /tmp/log' your-branch-here
[...]
$ cat /tmp/log
70d609ba7bc58bb196a2351ba26afc5db0964ca6,d9071b49743701c7be971f76ddc84e76554516c7
0d1146dcabc00c45fb9be7fe923c955f7b6deb50,cb6813f9aca5e5f26fcc85007c5bb71552b91017
[...]
```

(That file, of course, has the format `<original commit hash>,<new commit hash>`.)

I'm kind of curious what your intentions are with using this though. It doesn't seem like information you'd need to typically know if you're using filter-branch the "right" way (i.e., not manipulating existing published history).

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!! The -n was getting printed too for some reason, so I took that out. I don't mind the output being on alternating lines.

Don't worry, this is *not* a public repo. :-)

Comment: Oh, and it appears that $GIT_COMMIT is documented: "the $GIT_COMMIT
       environment variable will be set to contain the id of the commit being rewritten"

Comment: Ah, good. That's reassuring -- makes me a lot less worried that this will just magically stop working with the next release of Git. :-)

Comment: So, why is the `-n` getting printed? I don't like the output being on alternating lines.

Comment: I achieved it by replacing that command with `echo "${GIT_COMMIT},\c" >>/tmp/log; git commit-tree "$@" | tee -a /tmp/log`.