# Rewrite git history according to a .mailmap file

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Does git provide a way to **automatically** rewrite the history of a git repository history based on the substitutions specified in a `.mailmap` file (see `git help shortlog` for details)?

```
cd repository.git
somecommand /path/to/.mailmap # <-- ???
```

Comment: By writing the script that you are referencing here as `somecommand`. We can't guess what you expect it to do... Some of us may not even be familiar with what a `.mailmap` file is, or what it might contain...

Comment: The format of a git `.mailmap` file is documented in `man 1 git-shortlog`. Rephrased my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no short git command for this. One needs to use `git filter-branch --commit-filter <command> [...]` where `<command>` changes the `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` variables using `git check-mailmap` with `-c mailmap.file=/path/to/.mailmap` or `-c mailmap.blob=SOMEREV:path/to/.mailmap`, e.g to use a `.mailmap` file from the master branch, one can use

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    R=`echo "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME <$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL>" | git -c mailmap.blob=master:.mailmap check-mailmap --stdin`
    GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="${R% <*@*>}"
    R="${R##* <}"
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="${R%>}"
    R=`echo "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME <$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL>" | git -c mailmap.blob=master:.mailmap check-mailmap --stdin`
    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="${R% <*@*>}"
    R="${R##* <}"
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="${R%>}"
    git commit-tree "$@"
' HEAD
```

This should certainly work on systems with a POSIX shell.

Note that this does not rewrite any `Signed-off-by:` or similar lines in the commit messages.

Comment: I had a hard time doing this, because I didn't realize the `.mailmap` file was not in my history. Adding it as the last commit didn't work either. Looking in the documentation for git-config, I'll also found `mailmap.file`, which I could point to a file outside of the repository.

Instead of a `--commit-filter`, I used `--env-filter`, and replaced the `git commit-tree` command by the required `export` commands for the environment variables.

Comment: Note that if you have annotated tags, the documentation for  `--tag-name-filter` says: "There is also no support for changing the author or timestamp (or the tag message for that matter)." Which I think means that you need to rewrite those tags yourself with a `git tag` command.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this today, but combined with another `--commit-filter` (to obtain a mapping file of old-to-new commit ID's as per [How do I get a list of old->new rewritten commit SHAs from 'git filter-branch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14782906/2964696)).

I ended up using @BooK's excellent [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275187/rewrite-git-history-according-to-a-mailmap-file#comment65142892_27282679) as starting point, so lets turn that into a proper answer.

---

`git filter branch` provides the `--env-filter` option to change the meta-information *before* the commit, whereas `--commit-filter` affects it *during* the commit. This means we can separate the information fixing and the actual committing into two separate filter scripts

'Downside' is that `env-filter` needs to `export` the variables, so they persist to the commit-stage.

an env-filter version of [@jotik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282679/2964696) looks like this:

```
# make sure we have a copy of the mailmap that won't be affected by other parts of the filter-branch
cp .mailmap /tmp/mailmap

git filter-branch \
    --your-other-filters-here
    --env-filter '
    # fix author
    # apply mailmap to "current" person tagline, store in temp $R
    R=$(echo "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME <$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL>" | git -c mailmap.file=/tmp/mailmap check-mailmap --stdin)
    # extract mailmapped, pieces from $R using shell variable replacements
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="${R% <*@*>}"
    R="${R##* <}"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="${R%>}"

    # repeat for committer
    R=$(echo "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME <$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL>" | git -c mailmap.file=/tmp/mailmap check-mailmap --stdin)
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="${R% <*@*>}"
    R="${R##* <}"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="${R%>}"
'  -- --all
```

optional cleanup afterwards:

```
git rm .mailmap
git commit -m "delete mailmap after fixing history, no longer needed."
```