# git clone error "fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed"

Tags: git, clone

We are doing source control with git on Microsoft Team Foundation Server.
The git operation is mainly executed from VisualStudio.
I can not clone in a git repository in it.

Regarding the target git repository, I can commit, push, and pull in the repository already cloned, but if I try to clone newly, I get an error.

When I clone at the command prompt, the following message will be displayed.

```
git clone [my_repo_URI]
```

> remote: Found 8963 objects to send. (876 ms)
>   remote: A positive capacity must be specified for a Memory Mapped File backed by an empty file.
>   fatal: early EOF
>   fatal: index-pack failed

I investigated the error and tried the next thing, but a similar error occurred.

1. `git config - global http.postBuffer 524288000`
   `git clone [my_repo_URI]`
2. `git gc`
   `git repack - a - f - d - window = 250 - depth = 250`
   `git clone [my_repo_URI]`
3. `git clone --depth 1 [my_repo_URI]`

I'd like to make clone possible, how can I solve it?

Comment: What Git version are you using on the TFS server side? On the client side?

Comment: I do not know how to check the version of Git on the server side, but the version of TFS is "Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 3".
The git version on the client side is "git version 2.14.1.windows.1".

Comment: Can you try on the client side to use a Git 2.18?

Comment: I tried clone using the client side git version "git version 2.18.0.windows.1", but the situation did not change.  

As for the confirmation of the git version on the TFS side, we knew only the link information.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923482/which-version-of-git-does-team-foundation-server-use

Are there other ideas?

Comment: The error message comes from https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/ad219e63bcb048b7a2c7ddee85cb427e728ecd30/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedFile.cs#L70. Maybe a zero len file? (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/H_j0VE_TzU4)

Comment: I tried the clone after deleting all the zero len files, but the same error (fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed) occurs.